# Setting up a version control system across multiple servers?

Tags: svn, version-control

Currently I use free online SVN repositories, but I was considering hosting repositories on my own servers. Is there a way I can easily set up VCS so the same content is distributed across my servers?

Distributed version control sounds like what I'm looking for... unfortunately there are too many of them, and I need your opinions on what fits your needs the best. I'm the only one making any changes to the code, if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I use [unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com) who have a commercial SVN and GIT offering.  They in turn use Amazon EC2 and over the past 12months I've found them to be pretty reliable.

If you want to do this yourself though checkout GIT.

Comment: Unfuddle has been great...a little slow though. +1 for git.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [WANdisco](http://www.wandisco.com/), they provide a database replication layer for CVS and Subversion.

From the website:

> With WANdisco's clustering solutions, a central server is no longer a performance bottleneck. These solutions have no single point of failure whatsoever. WANdisco's approach is truly shared-nothing. There is no sharing of disk, CPU, or memory between servers in a cluster. WANdisco's clustering solutions support dynamic or static load balancing. Failover and recovery are automatic and transparent.